# How can I add storage bucket in JuiceFS?

Tags: ip-address

I am trying to learn how JuiceFS works.

So if I had two computers on the LAN with 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12 IP addresses, and a third with 192.168.1.100 (for metadata), and a fourth computer on the same LAN where I did this:

```
juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.11:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 myjfs  #metadata db

juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.12:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 myjfs  #metadata db
```

Can I mount the JuiceFS like this:

```
juicefs mount redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 ~/jfs
```

Will it appear as a filesystem with storage capacity of the two computer (192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12)?

Comment: try building a minio cluster if you are planning to use multiple nodes as jfs data storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, a juicefs filesystem composed of one database and one storage. So, only:

```bash
juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.11:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 myjfs  #metadata db
```

or only

```bash
juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.12:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 myjfs  #metadata db
```

is enough.

After the first command to create the file system is executed successfully, the second command will report an error.

So, when you mount the filesystem via:

```bash
juicefs mount redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 ~/jfs
```

You will be using the storage on 192.168.1.11:myjfs/, not 192.168.1.12:myjfs/.

Of course, if you wish to make full use of the storage space on both PCs, then you can format two file systems for use, noting that each file system should use a separate db. For example:

```bash
juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.11:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 myjfs1  #metadata db

juicefs format  \
    --storage sftp \
    --bucket 192.168.1.12:myjfs/ \ #remote sftp/ssh addresss and path
    --access-key tom \ #user
    --secret-key 123456 \ #pass
    redis://192.168.1.100:6379/2 myjfs2  #metadata db
```

Please note that `the filesystem name` and `the number of redis db`, and then you can mount them via:

```bash
juicefs mount redis://192.168.1.100:6379/1 ~/jfs1
juicefs mount redis://192.168.1.100:6379/2 ~/jfs2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will accept it.

What I was looking for is a way to expand the capacity of my filesystem on the fly by adding new nodes/computers to the network. Looks like you cannot do that with juicefs.

Maybe using overlayfs on top of juicefs would work, I don't know.

Comment: Maybe after mount ~/jsf1 and ~/jsf2, one could use mergefs  to merge the two. https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs

Comment: Perhaps minio is an option worth trying, where you can dynamically add more hosts to the storage cluster, accessible through the S3 API. Then you can use a similar tool like JuiceFS to improve the efficiency of access to the storage.